# .htaccess redirects to a template selection php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, content-management-system

How would I configure my .htaccess file if I want all requests to always load a core template selection file. I believe this could be good for a few reasons the first of which being security. Only if my php template selection code flags a file as safe for display will it display. Also, it allows me to build some interesting cms functionality like requiring a php metadata array in order to load the template file. How could I accomplish this?

Also, do you think it is practical to choose this method over others?

Comment: What is the template selection URL you want everything to be rewritten?

Comment: @anubhava, 'core/template.php'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess to make `core/template.php` your front controller:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^core/template\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . core/template.php [L]
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want even real files to be routed to same controller use last rule as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule !\.(jpe?g|ico|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ core/template.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: One problem with this, if test.php exists and I navigate to test.php in my browser, text.php is loaded instead of core/template.php

Comment: Do you really want `core/template.php` to be loaded for real files too? What if request comes for a css or js file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Make sure that inside the httpd.conf this line isn't commented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

(It should be **without** the '#' at the beginning)
And this is my directory tag (I'm using wamp but it should be the same, and of course restart the apache server if you changed something there)

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Didn't work, it gave me an internal 500 server error. I tried it with and without the IfModule unsure if that would make a difference.

Comment: I've added few more lines to the answer.

Comment: I would like this to be used in a piece of software that I will use to build client websites off of, is this really the best answer? It seems it requires a little too much backend fiddling for something I would like to work out of the box.

Comment: You do need that module to make it work. so yeah. you have to do it.